# Convert Persian date to standard English date

Tags: c#, datetime, textbox, persian

I have a textbox with this mask: `year/ month /day    hour :min`

The `datetime` format is `Persian`  like `1392/12/11 12:43`

I need to convert this string to standard English format so I used `pesiancalender` class.

[image]

As you can see the function `todate()` expects the values separately, I don't know how can I separate the string to this values! I mean I don't know how can I detect year and month and day and hour and min in string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) method with providing the date format to it with culture info about persian date.

---

Edit: [as I found out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.aspx):

> > Currently, the PersianCalendar class is not an optional calendar for any culture supported by the CultureInfo class and consequently cannot be a default calendar.

So, you can't use the approach I've suggested. Some investigation led me to the this [project for working with Persian date time](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17495/Persian-DateTime) and some hacks for the [`CultureInfo`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32096/How-to-Set-PersianCalendar-to-CultureInfo).

[Such questions were already on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10655116/213550), so I suggest to use their approach, and to write some helper class to solve your problem.