# How to convert Monthly calendar in c# to persain calendar

Tags: c#

Hi all I need to convert the monthly calendar in c# forms to persian calendar.
Any code for this please.I tried in google all have the code for converting todays date but not the entire calendar. please help

Comment: I hope this thread will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222427/convert-date-from-persian-to-gregorian

Comment: I want complete calendar not a single date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Convert Specific date to Persian use:

```
System.Globalization.PersianCalendar p = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
int year = p.GetYear(date);
int month = p.GetMonth(date);
int day = p.GetDayOfMonth(date);
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

And for Persian calender Follow this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17495/Persian-DateTime) and  **complete Persian calendar Asp.net** [Here](http://persianculture.codeplex.com/)

**Updated:**

[Persian Calender Ui for Winform application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13664/Farsi-Library-Working-with-Dates-Calendars-and-Dat)

Comment: I want UI type persian calendar in my form this is showing only date in console window.thanks for the reply

Comment: CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(“fa-Ir”);

//set Persian option to specified culture
PersianCultureHelper.SetPersianOptions(info); showing error while using

Answer (score 0):

their is PersianCalendar Class read msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.aspx

Comment: I cant undersatnd that can you tell me how to convert the monthly calendar in c# form to persian calendar