# how convert Georgian calendar to Persian calendar in c#

Tags: c#, calendar, windows-10

i convert Georgian calendar to Persian calendar by this code:

```
PersianCalendar t = new PersianCalendar();
date = t.GetYear(DateTime.Now).ToString("0000") + "/" + t.GetMonth(DateTime.Now).ToString("00") + "/" + t.GetDayOfMonth(DateTime.Now).ToString("00");
```

its work fine in application but when run app in windows 10 and location in Persian this code not work fro example:
when system date time this 2019/07/27 return 1398/05/05
but when system date time is 1398/05/05 return 2019/07/27
i want always return 1398/05/05 how fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you i tested your code and didn't find anything wrong with it. However you might want to check this answer by Jon Skeet in a similar question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11222462/5797040